# Cannot decrypt files using openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, macos-catalina

This is the command I used to encrypt the files on my Mac around 2017.  I don't know if my Mac was running High Sierra at the time or not, because I am usually late to the party when it comes to updates until I absolutely have to do so.

I was able to decrypt these files in 2018, but for some reason I cannot do so anymore.

```
tar cz folder_to_encrypt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e > out.tar.gz.enc
```

This is what I use to decrypt it now, using the same computer running Catalina

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in out.tar.gz.enc | tar xz
```

The error message I get is:

```
bad decrypt
4435975788:error:06FFF064:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:521:
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

I've read some posts talking about different versions of openssl and digests etc.  I downloaded an old version of of LibreSSL 2.3.6; it still fails but the error code is slightly different (06065064):

```
bad decrypt
4606180972:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:/Users/joe/Downloads/temp-libressl/libressl-2.3.6/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:529:
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

Comment: For real OpenSSL, the `enc` hash changed between 1.0.x and 1.1.x; see (my) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/#35614 . But you are using LibreSSL, which 'borrowed' the name for compatibility and confusion, and I don't know how that corresponds. You might try `-md md5` or maybe some other hashs anyway just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I tried what @dave_thompson_085 suggested, but didn't work in my case. I had to change the -md md5 to **sha256**.

Example to decrypt:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:yourpassword -p -in yourzip.enc -out youroutzip.zip -d -md sha256
```

This test was on a Mac with Big Sur 11.5.1 and openSSL through LibreSSL 2.8.3